# How do you use CSS Selectors to select multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have some HTML :

```
<div class="blah">
<div class="blah">
```

And I want to get all the divs with class 'blah'

```
var result = document.querySelector('.blah');
```

However the result is just the first element.

How do I get ***ALL*** elements?

Fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/pa5jpvsk/

Comment: document.querySelectorAll();

Comment: Did you really ask this question?

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+querySelector+for+multiple+elements&gws_rd=ssl](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+querySelector+for+multiple+elements&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: yes, sorry, i deserved those minus points :( I was lazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `querySelectorALL`

```js
var result = document.querySelectorAll('.blah');
console.log(result.length)
```

```html
<div class="blah">
<div class="blah">
```

Result are showed in the console.

With jQuery you can simplify it to:

`$('.blah');`

Comment: `var $ = function(sel) { return document.querySelectorAll(sel); };` jQuery is so incredibly unnecessary and completely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard one: `querySelectorAll()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns you a list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll